# Average distance between molecules

Tags: thermodynamics

**What is the average distance betweeen the gas molecules in a classroom?** 
I want to use that $$l= \frac{kT}{p \pi d^2 \sqrt{2}} $$ where $k$ is Boltzmann's constant and d the diameter of the molecule. But air is composed of many different types of molecules so that approach would be difficult, no? Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: The "average distance betweeen the gas molecules" has nothing to do with the mean free path, $l$.  Which did you want?

Comment: Are you talking about the [mean inter-particle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_inter-particle_distance)?

Comment: Average distance between the gas molecules is what I want. But I understand now why it is not the same as the mean free path.